# Object got unwanted lines

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, mirror-modifier

After joining the ear to the head by using bridge edge loops the structure got these unwanted lines. Please help to solve this issue.
[image]

Blender stack exchange: [image]

Comment: To me this does not look like as if there was simply a problem with the ear. This looks like there are two half faces (or at least parts of faces) on both sides which are slightly different, and the _Mirror_ modifier duplicates the left half over the right and vice versa. How does the face look like if you disable the _Mirror_ modifier? If this is not what's going on there, you should clarify how your mesh looks like or even better, upload your file at https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit your file into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object "Plane" represents the ear that has not yet been combined with the head [A]. You can hide this object by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> on your keyboard.

The other object, "Plane.001," represents the head that has been combined with the ear [B]. The unwanted lines are simply the result of two overlapping objects.

[image]

The "proportional editing" feature is enabled in the provided file. This feature lets you move objects that are close together, and because they overlap each other, they move as if they were one object. To deactivate proportional editing, press <kbd>O</kbd> on your keyboard.

[image: proportional editing]